# Scrolling scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView with multiple textfields in it. I notice that I'm able to scroll only if I put my finger on the background (i.e. not on textfield). When I try to scroll the view with a finger on the text field it won't scroll. Is this normal behavior ?

Comment: Have a look at the documentaion of UIScrollView:

– touchesShouldCancelInContentView:
  canCancelContentTouches  property
  delaysContentTouches  property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text field had multiple lines to it, you (or your users) would expect and hope it would scroll the content of the text field and not the parent scroll view, yes?

Perhaps what you want to do is subclass your text field and if you detect a touch event, pass it up the responder chain to the parent scroll view if it's a long touch (i.e. a scroll?).  Or, if you don't care about finger touches at all, your subclass can pass all touch events up to the parent view.

Or maybe just turn the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the text field to `FALSE`.